# How to query for row range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Is it possible to use Google Sheets' `=query` to select only a specific row range, e.g. rows 38 to 57 of sheet1?

Comment: Can't you just restrict the query to only operate on the data from those rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=QUERY(FILTER(A1:B,ROW(A:A)>=4,ROW(A:A)<=8),"select Col1, Col2")`

The query syntax has no option to use rows in `where` clause. I suggest using `query` + `filter`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. But, If you transpose them, then you could use them.

```
   =QUERY(TRANSPOSE(38:57),"Select *")
```